# (react native) How to center map view on user using Geolocation

Tags: react-native, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

1. HOW TO USE Geolocation.getCurrenPosition() SO IT CAN RETURN LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE OF THE USER

Answer (score -1):

In my app I use Expo managed workflow but the library is also available for bare React Native apps.  Docs can be found here:  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/

You need to have code to check for user permissions to collect their location by assuming this is granted, the following is an example:

```
    const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
      timeout: 10000,
    });
```

This returns the following payload for `location` above:  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationobject